# Loop through an array to create a 2D array - loop not working?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

The following should take the input and create a 2D array of letter pairs - [["A", "T"], ["T", "A"], ["C","G"]] but it is currently only returning [["A", "T"], ["T", "A"]], which makes me suspect there is something wrong with my loop logic.

```
function pair(str) {
var paired = [];
var str = str.split("");

for (i=0; i<str.length; i++) {

var newStr = str.splice(0,1);

  if (newStr[0] === "A") {
   newStr.push("T");
  }
  if (newStr[0] === "T") {
   newStr.push("A");
  }
  if (newStr[0] === "C") {
   newStr.push("G")
  }
  if (newStr[0] === "G") {
   newStr.push("C")
  }

paired.push(newStr);
}
   return paired;
}

pair("ATC");
```

Comment: when you splice , the array length decreases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `splice` is the problem. What you want is:

```
var newStr = [str[i]];
```

You need to index it at the character pointed by the index, and then wrap into `[]` because you want to treat it as an array.

In your original code, you didn't move forward with your loop at all. Worse, because `splice` modified the original string, its `length` changed as well, making the loop run less times than it should.

Answer (score 1):

Just to promote thinking functionally for more readable code, consider this way of writing it:

```
pair={"A":"T","T":"A","C":"G","G":"C"};

"ATC".split("").map(function(letter){return [letter,pair[letter]];})
```

`split` makes the string an array (as you already know), and then the array's `map` method lets you say, for each item in this array, use the function provided on that item to produce a new array.